# Nested position query with Xpath

Tags: xpath

```
<parentNode> 
   <divNodes> 
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
   </divNodes>
   <inputNodes>
       <input/>
       <input/>
   </inputNodes>
</parentNode>
```

In the above xml, I am given a node whose position is not known to me, and based on that node, I need to navigate to the corresponding Div node. So for example, if I am given the first input node, I would select the 1st div node; if I am given the 2nd input node, I navigate to the 2nd div node. Is there a way to create this kind of conditional query with xpath?

a pseudo code example of what I would like my xpath query to look like/accomplish::

```
input[./ancestor::parentNode/divNodes/div[position() = inputNodePosition]]
```

where inputNodePosition is the position() of the input node within InputNodes

Comment: Can you share some more details about what info is given, what is your desired output and what you've already tried?

Comment: i need to get the input node corresponding to the particular div node. input[./ancestor::parentNode/divNodes/div[position() = inputNodePosition]]